# How can I add some custom Text to my LocalizedStringKey?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
let sometext: LocalizedStringKey = "sometext"

var body: some View {
    Text(sometext + " some more text") // Error: Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'LocalizedStringKey' and 'String'
}
```

Why does this not work and how can I fix it?

I also found that, but I as a beginner do not really understand the answer
https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/d50afb/localizedstringkey_to_string/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you add text together in swiftUI.

```
var body: some View {
    Text(sometext) + Text("some more text")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to style both texts together?

Comment: You could try putting both in a `Group { }` and modify this.